# Automating object naming when importing multiple files in R

Tags: r, object

So, I downloaded a dataset containing 900 txt files, one for each biological sample. What I want to do is merge all of this data into one data matrix in R.

```
txt_files = list.files()

# read txt files into a list 
for (i in length(txt_files)){
  x <- read.table(file=txt_files[i], sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.name=1)
}
```

All files are in one folder, so I use `list.files()` to query all file names. Then I want to read each table into a separate R object (which is called x in this case). The problem is that I would like to name each object after the name of the actual file instead of x.

I've tried a couple of things and tried to search the internet, but haven't found a solution yet.
One thing I did find was to use lapply to import them all into a data list.

```
data_list = lapply(txt_files, read.table, sep = "\t")
```

However, I don't think this will be appropriate for me, since the data matrixes are not available anymore after this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: How do you mean "the data matrixes aren't available"? They're in `data_list`, surely?

Comment: if all the files have the same number of rows (and you have enough ram) `mydf <- do.call(rbind, mylist)` will construct a dataframe for you with all the observations. `rbind.fill` can additionally be used if not all data has the same structure, but is even slower than rbind (as it expands the df by one row at a time, which is extremely inefficient in R).

Answer (score 6):

Naming connected (especially sequential) things is in general a bad thing. The next thing you'll want to do is loop over these things, and that means constructing names by pasting bits together. Its a mess.

Store things in a list whenever possible. You've done that. I created a few CSV files:

```
> txt_files=c("f1.txt","f2.txt","f3.txt","f4.txt","f5.txt")
> data_list = lapply(txt_files, read.table, sep = ",")
> data_list[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
> data_list[[3]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  5  4  3
3  1  2  3
```

So now I can loop over them with `for(i in 1:length(txt_files))` and get the name of the file with `txt_files[i]` and so on:

```
> for(i in 1:length(txt_files)){
+ cat("File is ",txt_files[i],"\n")
+ print(summary(data_list[[i]]))
+ }

File is  f1.txt 
       V1          V2          V3   
 Min.   :1   Min.   :2   Min.   :3  
 1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:2   1st Qu.:3  
 Median :1   Median :2   Median :3  
 Mean   :1   Mean   :2   Mean   :3  
 3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:2   3rd Qu.:3  
 Max.   :1   Max.   :2   Max.   :3  
File is  f2.txt 
       V1          V2          V3   
 Min.   :1   Min.   :2   Min.   :3  
 1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:2   1st Qu.:3  
 Median :1   Median :2   Median :3  
 Mean   :1   Mean   :2   Mean   :3  
 3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:2   3rd Qu.:3  
 Max.   :1   Max.   :2   Max.   :3  
 ...
```

[etc]

Comment: or just `myfiles <- list.files; names(mydata) <- myfiles` normally works quite well (assuming that you don't read the files in a different order)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
names(data_list) <- txt_files
```

Or perhaps:

```
names(data_list) <- basename(txt_files)
```

Or maybe use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, `assign` might be applied in the following way:

```
txt_files = list.files()

# read txt files into a list 
for (i in length(txt_files)){
  x <- read.table(file=txt_files[i], sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.name=1)
  assign(paste(txt_files[i], "name", sep="."), x)
}
```

You can likewise use `get` to call back each created object:

```
x <- get(paste(txt_files[i], "name", sep="."))
```